Micronaut InterceptUrlMap not excluding paths of authorisation
I want to use intercept-url-map to deactivate security authorisation for some endpoints in test environment, but it still returned a message 'unauthorised'.
application-test.yml
micronaut:
  security:
    enabled: true
    intercept-url-map:
      - pattern: /dependency/**
        access: isAnonymous()

DependencyController
@Controller("/dependency")
@ExecuteOn(BLOCKING)
@Secured(SecurityRule.IS_AUTHENTICATED)
public class DependencyController {
}

